# Why does get_posts() work but not WP_Query( $args )?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have the following code snippet for wordpress:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1, // for safety, set the return value as 1 record
    'post_type'         => 'fs_ski_resorts',
    'meta_key'          => 'osm_geometry',
    'meta_value'        => $osm_geometry 
);
```

If I run dump $query = get_posts($args); which I believe is an ACF function, I get the queried post's values like ID, title, etc, as expected.

On the other hand, if I run $query = new WP_Query( $args ); zero posts are found ([p]=>0)

Am I misunderstanding something?  Any pointers much appreciated.  Why doesn't find any posts?

For info, the value of $osm_geometry is always something like 'way/123456';

Comment: `$query->p` isn't the number of posts found, you should use `$query->found_posts` for the count... or `$query->posts` for the actual results array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `get_posts()` is more basic built-in wordpress function (not ACF).
On the other hand with `WP_Query` you can be much more specific and it will return a lot more.

You can query like this:

```
    $args2 = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => 1, // for safety, set the return value as 1 record
        'post_type'         => 'page',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
            'key' => 'osm_geometry',
            'value' => $osm_geometry,
            'compare' => 'AND',
        ))
    );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Finally if you are looking to take the fields from ACF which is probably why you are looking inside `post_meta` you should look at the `get_fields()` function of ACF.
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_fields/

If you need more help, feel free to post what you get back (properly formatted):

```
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($query);
    echo '</pre>';
```